# CropImageView goes to default

Tags: android, android-custom-view

For cropping images in Android I'm using this library. [SimpleCropView](https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView#image-cropping)
which I find really useful.

My issue is that the cropping goes to default when the focus is not on the CropImageView for example when I select the cropping area, and then I try to put text on the EditText. the CropImageView goes to default

This the XML file.

```
   <com.isseiaoki.simplecropview.CropImageView
            android:id="@+id/cropImageView"
            xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
            custom:cropMode="ratio_1_1"
            custom:cropEnabled="true"
            custom:handleSize="10dp"
            custom:initialFrameScale="1.0"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

and this is activity code :

```
CropImageView cropImageView;

cropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.cropImageView);
cropImageView.setGuideShowMode(CropImageView.ShowMode.SHOW_ON_TOUCH);

cropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
cropImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
cropImageView.setGuideShowMode(CropImageView.ShowMode.SHOW_ON_TOUCH);
cropImageView.setTouchPaddingInDp(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

its bug inside library which can be easily fixed by replacing code inside setup layout

```
  private int prvW=0;
  private int prvH=0;

  private void setupLayout(int viewW, int viewH) {
    if (viewW == 0 || viewH == 0) return;
    if (prvW==viewW && prvH==viewH && mIsInitialized) return;
    prvH=viewH;
    prvW=viewW;


    setCenter(new PointF(getPaddingLeft() + viewW * 0.5f, getPaddingTop() + viewH * 0.5f));
    setScale(calcScale(viewW, viewH, mAngle));
    setMatrix();
    mImageRect = calcImageRect(new RectF(0f, 0f, mImgWidth, mImgHeight), mMatrix);

    if (mInitialFrameRect != null) {
      mFrameRect = applyInitialFrameRect(mInitialFrameRect);
    } else {
      mFrameRect = calcFrameRect(mImageRect);
    }

    mIsInitialized = true;
    invalidate();
  }
```